# Issues finding white board program

Tags: windows, whiteboard

I have been desperately looking for a white board program to write up class notes.  I found that I really like Microsoft white board but it is very strange.  I cannot access the white board files in any conventional way.  They just appear in the software GUI when I log into my microsoft account and are not organized.  I cannot find where they are saved and I don't like the idea of having my stuff saved online.  I want local files. (aren't there standards for 'whiteboard' files  or something like that?)

Is there any other white board interface that operates as a 'normal' type of software and has local files?  I am not interested in anything "collaborative" or "white board sharing."  I just want a digital platform to write my notes and save them as pdf's.

A local solution would be best, I cannot do anything cloud based or online storage as my job does not allow this. My system is Windows 10. I would be willing to pay, but wouldn't want to pay more than $50 or so bucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you just want to handwrite notes on a screen like paper, and save it as pdf?

OneNote is a popular choice (part of MSOffice AFAIK).

I am using [xournalpp](https://xournalpp.github.io/).  It is probably rather basic software but it does what I need, in particular I can sketch on pdf slides, add empty sheets, write and draw on those, and save the results as pdf.  It has some handwriting recognition (needs internet access), different backgrounds, colors, shapes, text and latex support and a little more bells and whistles.  Xournalpp is free (and open source).

I am using it with wacom tablet but touchscreen should work too.

Comment: I looked into OneNote and this seems to be what I am looking for! Thank you!